# Java android how import into project import com.zebra.sdk.comm.Connection;

Tags: java, android

I don not have idea how I can import this :

```
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.Connection;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.ConnectionException;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.discovery.DiscoveredPrinter;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.discovery.DiscoveredPrinterUsb;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.discovery.DiscoveryHandler;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.discovery.UsbDiscoverer;
```

I compile     compileSdkVersion 'Zebra Technologies Corp:EMDK APIs:26'

And I can not import this

Comment: The library look not imported

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i solved it.

Check this [link](http://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/android/) and click **Add ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar to my Eclipse/Android Studio Project**. Follow the steps.

it works for me.

You just need to get ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar and you can find it [here](https://github.com/dimagi/zebra-print-android/tree/master/app/libs)

I hope it helps you.